# Windows 8 Music Player Connect to iTunes/UPnP AV Server

Tags: windows-8, dlna, upnp

I have a NAS box which supports streaming music as either an iTunes or "UPnP AV" server.

I see very few settings in the music application. Can the standard Windows 8 music player be made to support either of these protocols?

Comment: It may help if you let us know the make/model of your NAS box

Comment: Really the question could be for any NAS, but for the record mine is a d-link dns-320